# Why does awk 'print' statement ignore the heading in my line?

Tags: unix, curl, awk, command-line, grep

[In MDN's command line introduction they print a network response heading to stdout.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Understanding_client-side_tools/Command_line#a_slightly_more_complex_example)

```
curl https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch -L -I | grep location
```

which returns this:

```
location: /en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch
```

My question is why does the awk 'print' statement ignore the header and only print path like below:

```
curl https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch -L -I | grep location | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

result:

```
/en-us/docs/web/api/fetch
```

Comment: please update the question with the expected output from the `curl / grep / awk` combo; right now you're telling `awk` to print the 2nd space-delimited field which is exactly what it's printing - `/en-us/docs/web/api/fetch`; if you change the code to `'{print $1}'` then it will print `location:`

Comment: @markp-fuso thank you, I didn't realize I was only printing the 2nd field.  Edit: I'm wiser after reading 4.2 Examining Fields source: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
awk '{ print $0 }'
```

$2 : print the second column
$0 : print all columns